# Can not decode the output of ipconfig

Tags: python, cmd

I want to assign output of ipconfig command to string but can not decode it.

When I try this:

```
import subprocess
out = subprocess.check_output("ipconfig",shell = True)
out = out.decode('utf-8')
print(out)
```

I get this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa7 in position 192: invalid start byte
```

What does cause this problem?

Comment: What python version and OS do you have? I tried it in Python 3.6 on Windows 10 and it worked fine.

Comment: What is the actual string you are trying to decode? Apparently it is not in UTF-8.

Comment: AFAIK Windows does NOT encode its output to UTF-8 but in an encoding that depends on your language. In french, Windows encode its output in ISO-8859-15

Comment: I am using Python 3.7 on Windows 10 @nick

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have issues with a locale. Try to pass `LANG=C` environment variable to subprocess.

```
out = subprocess.check_output("ipconfig", env={"LANG": "C"}, shell = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It works for now. I defined a function that encodes bytes to char one by one.

```
def cool_decode(rose):
    output = ""
    for i in rose:
        output = output + chr(i)
    return output
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you trying to encode hexadecimal as string. 
In my case (macOS) ipconfig wants added command like:

> waitall, getifaddr, ifcount, getoption, getpacket, getv6packet, set, setverbose

try to:

```
import subprocess
out = subprocess.check_output("ifconfig",shell = True)
out = out.decode('utf-8')
print(out)
```